# How to properly cycle through a JSON message from websocket?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, websocket, mobx

I need to cycle through five different types of JSON messages that I receive from WebSocket and start a function for appropriate type to make a change to observable in mobx. Any help?

For example the simple message looks like this:

```
{ 
    name: asd, 
    prefernces: { 
        pref1:fried fish, 
        pref2:fish sticks 
    }, 
    resident:true
}
```

or:

```
{ prevHistory: [
   {
     healthIssues: none,
     isOnLifeSupport:false,
   },
]
```

tried to do it like this

```
          for (const prop in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             return keyNames[prop];
         }
```

with keyNames being an object with keys that link me to the needed functions. But Eslint says that i shouldnt use  for ... in.

currently using it like this,it works but its sh*tty code.

```
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        value === name && someFunc();
        value === preferences && getPref();
        value === resident && isResident();
        value === prevHistory && getHistory();
    });
```

any tips how to solve it using Array.prototype.map()?

Comment: Please [show any research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) you've done, and [any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your json in this way:

```
json = { "name": "asd", "prefernces": { "pref1":"fried fish", "pref2":"fish sticks" }, 
   "resident":true}

for (var key in json) {
  console.log(json[key])
  if(key == 'type' && json[key] == 'value'){
     applyFunction(...)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take action depending on the schema of the object you receive, maybe you can do something like

```
if ('name' in myObj && 'preferences' in myObj)
  // Do something with this type of object
else if ('prevHistory' in myObj)
  // Do something with this other type of object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just define your mapping object that maps each property to specific function and that way you'll be able to see all mapping function just from one object.

```
const map = {
    name: (name) => {},
    preferences: (prefs) => {},
    resident: (resident) => {},
    prevHistory: (history) => {}
}
```

Then you would just enumerate your response object

```
Object.entries(response).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    var func = map[key];
    if (func) {
        func(value);
    }
});
```

This way you'll have a clean overview of all your mapping which will be called for every response property that is defined in your map.